MariaDB JSON: contains specific value in any sub attribute
I'm having a JSON like: {"a": {"z":true,"y":false}, "b": {"z":false,"y":false} }.
I need to obtain in MariaDB if there is any (sub) attribute in this JSON that contains the value "true".
I tried in SQL the following query:
SET @json='{"a": {"z":true,"y":false}, "b": {"z":false,"y":false} }';
SELECT  JSON_CONTAINS(@json,'true'),
        JSON_CONTAINS(@json,'true','$.a'),
        JSON_CONTAINS(@json,'true','$.a.z');

But the first two respond with 0 (zero), only the last one with 1. That means I can check $.a.z and $.a.y seperately and obtain with a case if any of them is true. I hope there is an other way to achieve this?

JSON_CONTAINS, doesn't support wildcards in the path, but JSON_SEARCH does.
it would also support true% and has even more possibilities
SET @json='{"a": {"z":true,"y":false}, "b": {"z":false,"y":false} }';

SELECT JSON_SEARCH(@json, 'all', 'true', NULL, '$.b') IS NOT  NULL;




JSON_SEARCH(@json, 'all', 'true', NULL, '$.b') IS NOT  NULL




0



SELECT JSON_SEARCH(@json, 'all', 'true', NULL, '$.a') IS NOT  NULL





JSON_SEARCH(@json, 'all', 'true', NULL, '$.a') IS NOT  NULL




1



fiddle

sounds to me like they just want a boolean result for all attributes: json_search(@json, 'one', 'true') is not null.  note that the documentation does not discuss what happens for non-string searches at all.

No he wants to check children and we simply don't know enough about his jjson

Thank you @nbk. This is exactly I was looking for: if any of the children of "a" has the value true, the search is true.  So the options "all" and "one" are both doing it.
